# Visual Studio Code C/C++ extension : The language server crashed 5 times in the last 3 minutes. It will not be restarted

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am using the C/C++ extension in visual studio code. I have been getting this error "The language server crashed 5 times in the last 3 minutes. It will not be restarted." for the last 1 week. I have tried to fix it using various versions of the C/C++ extension. Could anybody help me out, please?[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/za03j.png)

Comment: Upgrade all extensions?  Still crash? (No: done!)  Disable all extensions.  Does it still crash? (Yes: reinstall.) Enable half of the extensions.  Does it still crash?  (Yes: repeat with those extensions.  No: repeat with the other half.)  Isolate the problematic extension(s), assuming one-or-more of them is having issues, or inter-conflict.

Comment: @Eljay vs code even has a feature to do exactly that for you https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect